# PWA: service worker updated but not cached files

Tags: javascript, caching, progressive-web-apps

I'm currently trying to build a PWA from scratch. I have some troubles in handling updates.

Based on [this article](https://deanhume.com/displaying-a-new-version-available-progressive-web-app/), I wrote a code that displays a button when a new version of the service worker is available. When the button is clicked, the new worker is installed, and the shell files are stored in the cache.

To test this feature, I built a minimal example with only an `index.html` and a `service-worker.js` files.

```js
var cache_version = 'v2';
var cache_name = 'test-pwa-'+cache_version;

var shell_files = [
 './index.html'
];

self.addEventListener('message', evt => {
 if (evt.data.action == 'skipWaiting')
  self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('install', evt => {
 evt.waitUntil(caches.open(cache_name).then(cache => {
  return cache.addAll(shell_files);
 }));
});

self.addEventListener('activate', evt => {
 evt.waitUntil(caches.keys().then(key_list => {
  return Promise.all(key_list.map(key => {
   if (cache_name.indexOf(key) === -1)
    return caches.delete(key);
  }));
 }));
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', evt => {
 evt.respondWith(
  caches.match(evt.request).then(cache_response => {
   return cache_response || fetch(evt.request).then(response => {
    return caches.open(cache_name).then(cache => {
     cache.put(evt.request, response.clone());
     return response;
    });
   });
  })
 );
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Test of PWA</title>
 </head>

 <body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>

  <p id="refresh" style="display: none;"><button>New update!</button></p>

  <script>
   if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    var new_worker;
    var refreshing = false;

    navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', () => {
     if (refreshing)
      return;

     window.location.reload();
     refreshing = true;
    });

    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(registration => {
     registration.addEventListener('updatefound', () => {
      new_worker = registration.installing;

      new_worker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
       if (new_worker.state == 'installed' && navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
        var notification = document.querySelector('#refresh');

        notification.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
         new_worker.postMessage({action: 'skipWaiting'});
        });

        notification.style.display = 'block';
       }
      });
     });
    }).catch(err => {
     console.log('Something went wrong during the registration');
    });
   }
  </script>
 </body>

</html>
```

Now, I change the HTML file by, e.g., adding a new paragraph element after the title. Then, I change the `cache_version` variable in the service worker. When I reload the page, the update button is displayed. When I click on it, I can see (in Firefox tools) that the old cache is deleted, and a new cache folder is created as expected. However, the `index.html` file does not change (I don't see the new paragraph).

Any idea?

Comment: If the old cache folder is deleted, the `index.html` files is fetched again. Maybe Firefos's browser cache is getting in the way? Have you tried the "Disable Cache" option in the "Network" panel?

Comment: Didn't think about that, thank you for the idea. It seems to work.

However, I wonder now how to manage to make it work for a random user who won't necessary think about disable their cache.

But, again, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to C14L's comment, I found out that the issue was from HTTP Cache. For debugging, we can disable the cache from the browser's tools. For production, we can either bypass HTTP Cache or control it with an `.htaccess` file. I found some useful informations [here](https://enux.pl/article/en/2018-05-05/pwa-and-http-caching?language=en) for those who are interested.